# Checking if is Appendix or Chapter

Tags: conditionals, counters, appendices

How can i check if the value in `\thechapter` or `\value{chapter}` is a letter or a number?
That way i could identify if the counter is referring to a normal Chapter or an Appendix.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you're using the `book.cls`, you can check this way:

```
\makeatletter
\ifx\@chapapp\appendixname
  <whatever you want to do for an appendix>
\else <whatever you want to do for a regular chapter>
\fi
\makeatother
```

if you're using a different class, look for how `\chaptername` and `\appendixname` are used and adapt the above code appropriately.

**Edit:**

The question [Is there an "\if" command that determines if a command has been issued?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233238) provides an approach that can be used if `\@chapapp`is not defined by the class.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't knew about `\@chapapp`! Very useful

Comment: This seems failed on texlive2022.

Comment: I found a newer one https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233238/is-there-an-if-command-that-determines-if-a-command-has-been-issued

Comment: @Syvshc -- Thanks for the pointer.  This depends heavily on what document class is used, and the answers to that question make different assumptions.  Pointer added to this answer.