# Is there an "\if" command that determines if a command has been issued?

Tags: conditionals

I need to redefine the `\chapter` command to change the `\addcontentsline` command depending on whether or not the `\appendix` command has been issued. Is there an "if" command that determines if a command has been issued?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! :)

Comment: Something like a status variable?

Comment: Maybe you shoud redefine \appendix first

Comment: You can add a redefinition of `addcontentsline` to the definition of `appendix`, but in general the `@chapapp` approach is better.

Answer (score 7):

In general no, you can't tell `\empty` from nothing, however in at least `report` or `book` you can tell if `\appendix` has been used by looking at `\@chapapp` which will have definition `\chaptername` or `\appendixname` depending.

Answer (score 7):

In general, the only way to do this is to add it yourself. For example, specific to `\appendix`, you can add a boolean-switch like this:

> This is before the appendix.
>   This is after the appendix.

```
\documentclass{report}

\newif\ifinappendix% Default is \inappendixfalse
\let\oldappendix\appendix% Store \appendix
\renewcommand{\appendix}{% Update \appendix
  \oldappendix% Default \appendix
  \inappendixtrue% Set switch to true
}

\begin{document}

This is \ifinappendix after \else before \fi the appendix.

\appendix

This is \ifinappendix after \else before \fi the appendix.

\end{document}
```

[`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) also provides similar such switches as "boolean flags":

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{inappendix}% Default is \boolfalse{inappendix}
\appto\appendix{\booltrue{inappendix}}% Add boolean switch to \appendix

\begin{document}

This is \ifbool{inappendix}{after}{before} the appendix.

\appendix

This is \ifbool{inappendix}{after}{before} the appendix.

\end{document}
```

---

Extending David's answer, and this again is specific to your reference of `\appendix`, you can check the value of `\@chapapp`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\inappendix}{TT\fi\expandafter\ifx\@chapapp\appendixname}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is \if\inappendix after \else before \fi the appendix.

\appendix

This is \if\inappendix after \else before \fi the appendix.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ehm, the last solution is quite wrong. Try nesting it in a conditional where the `\ifinappendix` part is skipped by the outer conditional and you'll be surprised. In the `etoolbox` solution it's easier to say `\appto\appendix{\booltrue{inappendix}}` instead of going the `\oldappendix` route.

Comment: A fix for the last solution would be `\newcommand{\inappendix}{TT\fi\ifx\@chapapp\appendixname}` and the call is `\if\inappendix<true>\else<false>\fi`

Comment: @egreg: Yes. The use of an `\if...` *macro* rather than an `\if...` conditional is not appropriate. I'll update.

Comment: While just `T\fi` works, it is because TeX inserts a “frozen `\relax`” not to leave the conditional unfinished. Even simply `\fi` would work, but it's better to have two tokens for `\if`.

Comment: I created the new command \inappendix as suggested above. Then in the definition of \@chapter I inserted\if\inappendix
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}%
{\protect\numberline{\@chapapp\space\thechapter}#1}%
\else
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
{\protect\numberline{\@chapapp\space\thechapter}#1}%
\fi
However, the two appendices were entered in to ToC at the chapter level; not at the section level.

Comment: @CliffordWeil: Can you provide a sample document that I can copy-and-paste-and-compile?

Comment: Werner: Could my problem be the manner in which I'm trying to redefine \@chapter?

Comment: Werner: Could my problem be the manner in which I'm trying to redefine \@chapter? How does one redefine a command that's defined by \def rather than \newcommand? I can send a sample document as requested, but not enough characters are allowed.

Comment: @CliffordWeil: Use [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/) and provide a link to the code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the command \ifx directly, but couldn't use \@chapapp to compare to \chaptername. I defined \newcommand{\chapname}{Chapter} for that purpose. Specifically, I used \ifx\chaptername\chapname, which worked perfectly!