# How to check if a definition of a command is used more than once?

Tags: macros

Last time I asked: [How to check if command is used more than once?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410814/how-to-check-if-command-is-used-more-than-once)

This time I want LaTeX to throw an error message if two or more commands have the same definiton.

**This is allowed**

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\one}{Definition 1}
\newcommand{\two}{Definition 2}
\newcommand{\three}{Definition 3}

\begin{document}

\one

\two

\three

\end{document}
```

**This is should throw an error message**

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\one}{Definition 1}
\newcommand{\two}{Definition 1} % Definition already exists!
\newcommand{\three}{Definition 3}

\begin{document}

\one

\two

\three

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

- I'd like to have the error at point of definition.
- It's an error if the definition already exists in another command.

Comment: Do you want the error at point of definition or at point of use?

Comment: you can easily test whether any two specified commands have the same definition but you can not check whether _any_ other command has the same definition of the one have just defined. Please clarify your question to make it clear what you want to test.

Comment: @Manuel: I updated my question.

Comment: @Sr.Schneider That's what I give in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\newuniquecommand` instead of `\newcommand`.

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \newuniquecommand { m O{0} o +m }
 {
  \bool_set_false:N \l_schneider_alreadydefined_bool
  \prop_map_inline:Nn \g_schneider_commands_prop
   {
    \str_if_eq:nnT { ##2 } { #4 }
     {
      \bool_set_true:N \l_schneider_alreadydefined_bool
      \prop_map_break:
     }
   }
  \bool_if:NTF \l_schneider_alreadydefined_bool
   { <ERROR! add what you want to output in case of error> }
   {
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g_schneider_commands_prop { #1 } { #4 }
    \IfValueTF {#3}
     { \newcommand #1 [#2] [#3] {#4} }
     { \newcommand #1 [#2]      {#4} }
   }
 }
\bool_new:N \l_schneider_alreadydefined_bool
\prop_new:N \g_schneider_commands_prop

\ExplSyntaxOff
```